# ios how dismiss UIImagePickerController after use

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I develop an app that take a picture from camera unitl here all well bat after receive from his delegate i dismiss and i receive exc_bad_access here is the code:

declare and open the camera:

```
-(void)ScattaFoto{
 UIImagePickerController *picke = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   // Delegate is self
   picke.delegate = self;

    // Allow editing of image ?
picke.allowsEditing=NO;


if(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) {
      picke.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
     }else{
    picke.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

   // Show image picker
[self presentModalViewController:picke animated:YES];
```

}

and than is the delegate event:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picke   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
// Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
//UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// [picker release];
[self  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; // Here i receive exc_bad_access
[picke release];
}
```

i put on .h the refer to delegate of imagePickerControl "UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate"

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picke didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [picke  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Comment: i try to change self to picke bat nothing always the same "exc_bad_access"

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
       [picker.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ARC is releasing your UIImagePickerController before didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called?

Try placing your UIImagePickerController in a @property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *picke;
```

[You can read more about @properties here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

You will still have to allocate and initialize the UIImagePickerController before you use it.

Comment: you say me to try @property(nonatomic,retain)UiImagePickerController ...?

Comment: i try to use property work sometime,bat i receive the same error,if i have picker in @property in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo whick picker or picker i dismiss?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you targetting?

Comment: I edited my original answer with more information concerning the @property

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question though; you would dismiss the picker in the property you declared like this: `[self.picke dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: i try to set property bat i have the same problem when i try to dismiss the picker

Comment: i try also self.picker bat nothing

Comment: maybe now i understand why have that problem,because in the event for dismitt the picket i do other not only dismitt so i have that problem